# Simple authentication using Servlet and Mysql

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I am trying to create Simple login page. Here's my code:

**Servlet :**

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    @WebServlet("/MySQLConnect")
    public class MySQLConnect extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       //do post method calling
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String user = request.getParameter("user");
            String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javademo", "root", "admin");
                //prepared statement for calling query
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select user,pass from login where user=? and pass=?");
                pst.setString(1, user);
                pst.setString(2, pass);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    out.println("Correct login credentials");
                } 
                else {
                    out.println("Incorrect login credentials");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{}

        }
        }
```

**index.html:**

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="MySQLConnect">        
            UserName :<input type="text" name="user" /><br/><br/>
            Password :<input type="password" name="pass" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<display-name>AuthenticationUsingMySQL</display-name>

        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MySQLConnect</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MySQLConnect</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MySQLConnect</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

I am trying to open the page using

http://localhost:8080/AuthenticationUsingMySQL/Login

But it is showing `HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported` by this URL

Comment: You have both annotation based servlet config @WebServlet and web.xml at same time, why ?

Comment: please call http://localhost:8080/AuthenticationUsingMySQL/index.html for login-page. this should display the login-form. submitting the form via post should call your servlet. maybe you need to fix/check some urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to http://localhost:8080/AuthenticationUsingMySQL/Login on your browser you send GET request to your servlet which doesn't provide GET method.
Just go to http://localhost:8080/AuthenticationUsingMySQL/ and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use te URL in the Browser as your webservlet supports POST request, so try to POST the request from JSP only or use the tools like POSTMAN, SOAPUI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open that link in your browser then that error makes sense.  You need to use a tool like Fiddler, or set up a javascript test method, to test your code.  It looks like you are constructing a POST method in your code.  Web browsers, by default, use GET to access web resources, thus the need for a different tool which is able to perform a POST.  Otherwise you will need to modify your code so it accepts GET requests.